# Calculate sum of Primary and Secondary Diagonal in square matrix

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently calculating diagonal for `n x n` square matrix. I can able to calculate Primary diagonal with below code.

```
function calculateDiagonal($array) {
    $length = count($array);
    $primary = 0;
    $secondary = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++):
        for ($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++):
            if ($i == $j):
                $primary += $array[$i][$j];
            endif;
        endfor;
    endfor;
    $totalSum = $primary + $secondary;
    return $totalSum;
}
```

Can anyone help me to calculate sum of secondary diagonal.

check this as a reference.
[image]

Comment: Hint: `i+j` sum should be 3)

Comment: So you mean to say `i+j = n`, right?

Comment: Counting from 0 - `n-1`

Comment: You don't need two loops `
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++):
  $primary += $array[$i][$i];
  $secondary += $array[$i][$length-$i-1];
endfor;`

Comment: @splash58 : Perfect. Unexpected with one loop.Great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with this. You can do sum of diagonal with minimum iteration.

```
    $a = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]];
    $n = 4;//nxn matrix
    $d = $s = 0; //initialize both diagonal sum to 0
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $d += $a[$i][$i];
        $s += $a[$i][$n - $i - 1]; 
    }
    var_dump($d);//primary diagonal total
    var_dump($s);//secondary diagonal total
```

Comment: Cool. Working perfect. Wasn't expected in one loop. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function calculate2Diagonal($array) {
    $length = count($array)-1;
    $primary = 0;
    $secondary = 0;
    echo $length;
    for ($i = $length; $i >= 0; $i--):
        for ($j = $length; $j >=0; $j--):
            if ($i == $j):
                $primary += $array[$i][$j];
            endif;
        endfor;
    endfor;
    $totalSum = $primary + $secondary;
    return $totalSum;
}
```

Only a for inverse ;)

Comment: @virendra-jadeja is a elegant solution, but If your question is an exercise, your teacher will look for an inverse bulcle

Answer (score 1):

Just using the function [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php):

```
function diagonalSum($arr) {
    $i = 0; 
    $n = count($arr);
    return array_reduce($arr, 
        function  ($c, $str) use (&$i, $n ) {
        $i++;
        return $c + $str[$i-1] + $str[$n-$i];
    }, 0);
}
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/aauMWI)